# J3.6 template errors

Tags: templates

I just upgraded a Joomla site from 3.2 to 3.6 an am receiving errors when going to edit any template (even Protostar) in Extensions->Templates->Templates->(click on my theme). The theme works great on the frontend. The errors are:

1. The template folder is not writable. Some features may not work. Template folder not found.
2. Warning: ksort() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /home/xxxxx/public_html/administrator/components/com_templates/views/template/tmpl/default_tree.php on line 11
3. Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/xxxxx/public_html/administrator/components/com_templates/views/template/tmpl/default_tree.php on line 15

Comment: Can't say for sure, because you didn't mention template name and version, but it seems that template needs to be updated to be compatible with J3.6

Comment: These same errors occur even with Protostar.

Answer (score 3):

I got it fixed. I had to go into Extensions -> Manage -> Discover, then click Discover. Then all of the template options worked and filled with their relevant theme info.